# LUA A function and an array, declared id, null ariable?

Tags: arrays, function, variables, lua, declare

I have a problem with a function and an array since yesterday. It seems that lever ID is not declared or something...

Here is my code:

```
function tpp(leverID, from, to)

if item.uid == leverID and item.itemid == 1945 then

    local count_players = #to
    local store = {}

    for i = 1, count_players do
        local pid = getTopCreature(from[i]).uid
        if (pid == 0 or not isPlayer(pid)) then
                return doPlayerSendCancel(cid, 'You need ' .. count_players .. ' players to use this lever.')
        end
        store[i] = pid
    end

    for i = 1, count_players do
        doSendMagicEffect(from[i], CONST_ME_POFF)
        doTeleportThing(store[i], to[i], false)
        doSendMagicEffect(to[i], CONST_ME_TELEPORT)
    end

    doTransformItem(item.uid, item.itemid + 1)

elseif item.uid == leverID and item.itemid == 1946 then
    doTransformItem(item.uid, item.itemid -1)
end

end




function onUse(cid, item, fromPosition, itemEx, toPosition)


local pos = {
    ['pos_start'] = {
            {['x'] = 1059, ['y'] = 1034, ['z'] = 7},
            {['x'] = 1060, ['y'] = 1034, ['z'] = 7}
    },
    ['pos_end'] = {
            {['x'] = 1059, ['y'] = 1032, ['z'] = 7},
            {['x'] = 1060, ['y'] = 1032, ['z'] = 7}
    }
}

tpp(10150, pos['pos_start'], pos['pos_end'])

return true


end
```

I get the this error:

> attempt to index global 'item' (a nil value)

I am new to lua. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to pass 'item' variable to tpp() function when you called it from onUse() function.

Since there was no 'item variable in scope of tpp() function, or in its arguments, variable considered to be global, and there's no global variable with that name.